# How to insert picture on top of RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I currently have a page on an app I'm working for a client. The page in question has an image on top of it, a banner i've been using. Below that is a recycler view with cards that hold news information which are constantly changing everyday. I did this before on the iOS version of this app where I put the image banner into the recyclerview(on iOS its called a collection) on the very top and then when you'd scroll through the recyclerview the image would move up and down with the scroll. Is there any way where I can set the image banner into the recyclerview at the very top so it scrolls up and down with the cards in the recyclerview, as opposed to being outside the recyclerview.

The image banner takes up a lot of space which is why i want to insert it into the recyclerview so it frees up space on the screen when scrolling to view more cards at the same time. See images below

[How the recyclerview looks without scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjI8E.png)
[How the recyclerview looks after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI4yP.png)

```
public class News extends Fragment {

private static final String url = "somenewsurl";    //news url
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private List<NewsItem> news;
private RecyclerView rv;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

public News() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //initialize variables
    news = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new NewsRvAdapter(news, getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    //set up linear layout manager
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    //set up recycler view
    rv = getView().findViewById(R.id.news_rv);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    newsData();     //parse json data
}
```

Here is the other file used for this page with the image and recylerview

```
public class NewsRvAdapter extends          RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsRvAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<NewsItem> newsList;

//default constructor
public NewsRvAdapter(){}

public NewsRvAdapter(List<NewsItem> newsList, Context context){
    this.newsList = newsList;
    this.context = context;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public NewsRvAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_card, viewGroup, false);
    final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NewsRvAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    myViewHolder.title.setText(newsList.get(i).getTitle());
    myViewHolder.description.setText(newsList.get(i).getDescription());

    //Load image URL using Picasso
    Picasso.get()
            .load(newsList.get(i).getImageUrl())
            .centerCrop()
            .fit()
            .into(myViewHolder.photoUrl);

    //on click listener that opens url in webview
    myViewHolder.photoUrl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String link = newsList.get(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getLink();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //onclick that opens new activity
    myViewHolder.description.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, SingleNews.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("title", newsList.get(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getTitle());
            i.putExtra("urlToImage", newsList.get(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getImageUrl());
            i.putExtra("publishedAt", newsList.get(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDate());
            i.putExtra("content", newsList.get(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getContent());
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newsList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView title, description;
    ImageView photoUrl;
    LinearLayout viewContainer;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_description);
        photoUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_photo);
        viewContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsView_container);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
tools:context=".News">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/news" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img"
    android:id="@+id/news_rv">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Heres the error:
2019-08-19 11:36:13.788 14829-14829/com.example.gabe.politicianspulse E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gabe.politicianspulse, PID: 14829
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.gabe.politicianspulse:layout/fragment_news: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.gabe.politicianspulse:layout/fragment_news: Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.gabe.politicianspulse:layout/fragment_news: Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

Comment: to achieve this, you'd probably need to create (and inflate) a view with that component IN to your recycler view, sort of how you add other items to a recycler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your layout with [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView)

It will be like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".News">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/news" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/news_rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img" />
        </LinearLayout>
      </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And don't forget to disable nested scroll on your `recyclerview`
by calling `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` with your `recyclerView` reference object.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow. I'm fairly new to android studio

Comment: This is what I have for the xml for that page

Comment: @Flash_Stang can you post your xml. so that i can help ?

Comment: I posted the xml in the question now

Comment: thanks. As far as disabling the setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) where would that go? Into the first java file or the second?

Comment: in your News fragment use rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: I made this change to the xml file but now the app crashes on startup

Comment: I also made the change to the news fragment and it still crashes

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any errors. Under build i have all green check marks but the app still crashed

Comment: Post the crash from your logcat.

Comment: Here it is, there's a lot more to it but this is what i think might help:

Comment: I inserted the crash from the logcat at the end of question

Comment: If you use this solution, you have to choose between one of two problems. Either you have to use `wrap_content` for the RecyclerView height (which will cause you to lose all the performance benefits of RecyclerView) or you will not be able to have the image scroll with the RecyclerView contents.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Flash_Stang You're welcome. don't forget to upvote and mark it as answer :)  
Also check Ben P answer's below.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve a similar solution to your iOS solution by creating an adapter that uses different *item view types* alongside a list that contains your banner image + many "post" items.

It's very verbose, but we can do a quick summary here:

First, create a class to represent the banner image. Maybe a `BannerItem` class that has an `imageId` field or similar.

Second, in your adapter, change your list from `List<NewsItem>` to `List<Object>` (gross, I know). Create this list by first adding one `BannerItem` and then adding your `NewsItem`s.

Override `getItemViewType()` in your adapter to indicate which items are banner images and which are news cards:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object item = list.get(position);

    if (item instanceof BannerItem) {
        return 0;
    } else if (item instanceof NewsItem) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        throw new AssertionError("item can only be a banner image or news post");
    }
}
```

Then, in your `onCreateViewHolder()` and `onBindViewHolder()` methods, you can create/populate a different kind of `ViewHolder` based on the item view type.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == 0) {
        // is a banner image - return a BannerViewHolder
    } else if (viewType == 1) {
        // is a news post - return a NewsViewHolder
    } else {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
```

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder.getItemViewType() == 0) {
        // is a banner image - cast holder to BannerViewHolder
    } else if (holder.getItemViewType() == 1) {
        // is a news post - cast holder to NewsViewHolder
    } else {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
```

A web search for `recyclerview getitemviewtype` should provide you with plenty of tutorials. At a quick glance, this one seems reasonable: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView